Background noise in OBS Studio Screen Recording in Ubuntu 22.04
I have just installed OBS Studio on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop, and started using it, trying to video record the whole screen of the laptop. I have followed the instructions at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2JEjeehf4k.
It works as expected except for one thing : there is a loud crackling background sound on the whole video (even when there is no sound in the original video). How can I fix this ?
